# Calculate Operator norm of a given operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, compact-operators

I have the following operator on a Hilbert space:

$$T=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}\langle a_{n}\mid \cdot\rangle b_{n},$$

where the $c_{n}$ is a bounded sequence of complex numbers and $a_{n},b_{n}$ are two orthonormal families.

I have to show that the operator norm of $T$ is the maximum of the $c_{n}$.

Using the definition of the operator norm I have after some steps:

$$\Vert T\Vert=...=\sup_{\Vert x\Vert =1}\sqrt{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\vert c_{n}\vert^{2}\vert\langle a_{n}\mid x\rangle\vert^{2}}$$

I don`t know how to proceed. I should find that $\Vert T\Vert = \max_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\vert c_{n}\vert$. So I had the idea to show $\leq$ and $\geq$. Using the Bessel's inequality I get $\Vert T\Vert\leq \max_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\vert c_{n}\vert$, but I don't how to show the other direction ....

Comment: It seems like the RHS is missing a square root.

Comment: Thanks thats true....

Comment: Once you have that, you get $\|T\| \leq \max |c_n| := \lambda$. Pix $x = a_{N(\lambda)}$ where $N(\lambda)$ is such that $c_{N(\lambda)} = \max |c_n|$. Then, $\|x\| = 1$ and $\|Tx\| =  \max |c_n|$.

Comment: You are allowed to pull $\max |c_n|^2$ out of the sum getting something bigger.

Comment: Thanks a lot so far.... What if my sequence doesn't have a maximum? In this case we should find $\Vert T\Vert =\sup_{n} \vert c_{n} \vert$ I guess.... Do you know how to argue in this case?

Comment: Is it right to argue in the same way? Like we know by choosing $x=c_{n}$ we see that $\vert c_{n}\vert\leq \Vert T\Vert$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and therefore $\sup_{\Vert x\Vert=1}\vert c_{n}\vert\leq \Vert T\Vert$

Comment: @Udalricus.S. I believe the sequence needs to have a maximum, otherwise the sum is not absolutely convergent right?

Answer (score 1):

You have that $\|T\|^2=\|T^*T\|$. And
$$
T^*Tx=\sum_{n,m}c_n\overline{c_m} \overline{\langle a_n,x\rangle}\,\langle b_n,b_m \rangle\, a_n
=\sum_n|c_n|^2\,\langle x,a_n\rangle\,a_n.
$$
From this you see that, since the maps $\langle\cdot,a_n\rangle a_n$ are a family of pairwise orthogonal projections,
$$
\|T^*T\|=\max\{|c_n|^2:\ n\}. 
$$